# Check and Merging two array

Tags: php, arrays

### What I am Doing:

I am creating a navbar. In this in am getting value from database. In my database in have three columns `page_name` , `main_page` , `sub_page` .

**Represented like this:**

```
 ID   |   Page Name   |   Main Page   |   Sub Page   |
  1   |  Home         |   1           |   0          | 
  2   |  About        |   1           |   0          |
  3   |  Our Work     |   0           |   2          |
  4   |  Contact      |   1           |   0          |
```

- If it is a `Main Page` then its `main_page` = `1` and `sub_page` = `0`.
- If it is a `Sub Page` then its `main_page` = `0` and In `sub_page` has the the `id` of `main_page`.

**I am getting these value from database from this this query:**

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
```

**And checking my result if it is `Main Page` or `Sub Page` and adding them in a array:**

```
foreach($result as $row){
            if ($row['main_page'] == '1') {
                $main_page[] = $row['page_name'];//if main page the add them in array
            }else{
                $result1 = "";
                $query1  = "SELECT page_name FROM subjects WHERE id = '$row[sub_page]'";//getting name of main_page
                $result1 = $this->db->query($query1)->result_array();
                $main_page_name = $result1['0']['page_name'];
                $sub_page       = $row['page_name'];
                echo $main_page_name; echo "<br/>";
                $main_sub[] = array('main_page' => $main_page_name, 'sub_page' => $sub_page);//if sub page add main page name and sub page     
            }
 }
```

**After that it is returing me this result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Home
    [1] => About
    [2] => Contact
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [main_page] => About
            [sub_page] => Our Work
        )
)
```

### What I am trying to Do:

**How can I merge these two array's to get a array like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Home
    [1] => About
         (
            [sub_page] => Our Work
         )
    [2] => Contact
)
```

#### Is it possible to get result like this from these two array or any other way to get this result?
please tell me I get stuck here.

Comment: Yes, it is possibile. First query, select * etc... where sub page = 0. For each element launch -> select * from mytable where sub_page = thisid (thisid is the current element) so with a loop you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this

```
Array(
    [0] => array(
       "title" => "Home"
    ),
    [1] => array(
       "title" => "About",
       "sub_page" => array(
          [0] => "Our Work"
       )
    ),
    [2] => array(
       "title" => "Contact"
    )
)
```

Above result can be achieved by doing this

```
    $pageArray = array();
foreach($result as $row){
            if ($row['main_page'] == '1') {
                $pageArray[$row['id']]["title"] = $row['page_name'];
            }else if($row['sub_page']) {
                $pageArray[$row['sub_page']]["sub_page"][] = $row['page_name'];     
            }

 }
```